# Как изменить ID3 тэги аудио файла?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, аудио, id3v2

На данный момент могу только читать их разными методами. Первый с помощью CoreAudio. Второй с помощью [Taglib](https://taglib.github.io/).

Для второго способа я не могу найти примеров. Поскольку, для меня, там все сложно.

Для первого способа я так понимаю надо использовать

```
AudioFileSetProperty
```

Однако какое свойство указывать не понятно. Так как такие свойства как

```
kAudioFormatProperty_ID3TagToDictionary, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary
```

только на чтение.

Comment: Чтоб изменить ID3 таги, как и любую другую метадату файла, его надо полностью пересобрать с новой метадатой. Очень сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать доступными через CoreAudio способами. ffmpeg или libav в помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такое [решение](https://github.com/decarbonization/TagLib):

```
TLMetaData *myMetaDataPlayer;
myMetaDataPlayer = [[TLMetaData alloc] initWithURL:url openReadOnly:NO error:nil]; //инициализировали
[myMetaDataPlayer setTitle:@"newTitle"]; //поменяли
[myMetaDataPlayer synchronizeValuesWithMetaData:myMetaDataPlayer]; //сохранили
```